# Record user login for audit on IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a server running for Identity only for authentication and I want to log every user login.
I've read the Identity doc and tried using the [`IEventSink`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/events.html). It's supposed to be easy, but Login keeps working without calling the EventSink. 
Do I have to register my class somewhere? What am I missing?

```
var builder = services
.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
}
)
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
.AddOperationalStore(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
        b.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    );
    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
});
```

This is the EventSink I created:

```
public class MyEventSink : IEventSink
{
    public Task PersistAsync(Event evt)
    {
        if (evt.Id.Equals(EventIds.TokenIssuedSuccess))
        {
            var _test = evt as TokenIssuedSuccessEvent;
        }
        throw new System.NotImplementedException(); // shouldn't even login
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought about it, but I didn't find it on the docs or in any other question on how/where to do it.

Comment: On the opposite, I'll delete my comments and let you post that as an answer. The docs aren't completely clear about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @camilo-terevinto pointed out to me, I just wasn't registering my `MyEventSink` as a service.
I needed the following line in my startup, so when I set `Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true` the IdentityServer knows it is my service it should call:

`services.AddScoped<IEventSink , MyEventSink>();`